# Easy way to split a terrain mesh into sections?

Tags: 3d

I've created a piece of **3D terrain** and converted it to Wavefront `OBJ`. It is `64 x 24 x 64` units in size. Is there a quick way to split the terrain mesh into `8 x 24 x 8` sections?

I don't want to render them all at one time. Thanks!!

Comment: Do you need to keep texture coordinates?